# Using a variable in a script calling curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I'm trying to replace **1.2.3.4** with the contents of variable **$wanip** in the following script.

```
wanip="4.3.2.1"
echo $wanip
content=$(curl --insecure -H "X-DNSimple-Token: foo:bar" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{\"record\": {\"name\": \"foo\",\"content\": \"1.2.3.4\"}}" https://acme.com/records/123)
echo $content
```

If I literally replace *1.2.3.4* with $wanip*, when I run the script I'm getting a message saying: *"message":"Problems parsing JSON"*.

Comment: Works for me. Try using `set -x` before the command (and `set +x` after). It should print `++ curl --insecure -H 'X-DNSimple-Token: foo:bar' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"record": {"name": "foo","content": "4.3.2.1"}}' https://acme.com/records/123` -- if it prints something else, that may point to the problem.

Comment: put a set -x in the line before content?  If so, that is giving me an illegal operation message

Comment: "illegal operation", or ": invalid option"? If the latter, your script may be in DOS/Windows format rather than unix, which will cause all sorts of weird problems. Try printing the script with `cat -vt scriptname`, and see if it lists "^M" at the end of lines. If it does, use something like `dos2unix` or `sed -i $'s/\r$//' scriptname` to fix it, and then stay away from Windows text editors for unix scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a layer of abstraction:

```
#!/bin/bash
wnip="4.3.2.1"
echo $wanip
command="curl --insecure -H 'X-DNSimple-Token: foo:bar' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{\"record\": {\"name\": \"foo\",\"content\": \"${wnip}\"}}' https://acme.com/records/123"
echo $command
content=$($command)
echo $content
```

Comment: I'm getting several "couldn't resolve host" curl errors with this

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit try this

Answer (score 0):

After some hacking, I got this to work.  Strange.

```
wanip=\"4.3.2.1\"
echo $wanip
content=$(curl --insecure -H "X-DNSimple-Token: foo:bar" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{\"record\": {\"name\": \"foo\",\"content\": $wanip }}" https://acme.com/records/123)
echo $content
```